# Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

i have a generator `rev_generator` that yields a tuple of two elements `(numpyarray of shape (1279,300,1) , int value: 0 or 1)`

then i pass it to:

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(rev_generator,
                                      output_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1279,300,1),dtype=tf.float32),
                                                       tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)))
```

and then a simple model

```
inputs=tf.keras.Input(shape=(1279,300,1,))
x=tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
x=tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D()(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
outputs=tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(...)
```

but when i call `fit`

```
model.fit(train_ds,epochs=epochs, batch_size=32)
```

it throws me an error:

> ```
> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_2: expected shape=(None, 1279, 300, 1), found shape=(1279, 300, 1)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `tf.data.Dataset` API, you should set the batch size explicitly and not in `model.fit`:

```
train_ds = train_ds.batch(32)
...
...
model.fit(train_ds,epochs=epochs)
```

See [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit):

> Integer or None. Number of samples per gradient update. If
> unspecified, batch_size will default to 32. **Do not** specify the
> batch_size if your data is in the form of datasets, generators, or
> keras.utils.Sequence instances (since they generate batches).

Also note that your input shape does not match your input data. You are mixing up 1279 and 1297. Here is a working example:

```
def gen():
  yield tf.random.normal((1279,300,1)), tf.random.uniform((), maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen,
                                      output_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1279,300,1),dtype=tf.float32),
                                                       tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)))

inputs=tf.keras.Input(shape=(1279,300,1,))
x=tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
x=tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D()(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
outputs=tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(train_ds.batch(32),epochs=5)
```

Comment: Thank you, the shape  was just a typo, it works fine on my script, can you plz point me to some really good sources where i can learn more about "tf.data.Dataset.from_generator", and tf.data in general, not tensorflow website